# How to save any file to SQL Server 2008 R2 using vb.Net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I need to save files as attachments like (pdf ,word, images ..etc ) in SQL Server 2008 R2 using vb.Net and open it after save if I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with Simon's #1 suggestion. You can just store a relative path for the file - relative to the root of wherever your file store is on a filesystem accessible to the user. #2 has issues with backup and recovery - you are just making the database unnecessarily large by storing all that binary data for little real gain. Both methods will need clients to get to the data. #2 may consume significant server and client resources just to recreate the file - certainly won't scale well for high access rates or high data volume.

Comment: In general I agree with @rheitzman. I didn't specify a choice as I don't know enough about the surrounding system but yes, in general if possible I'd go with this.

Answer (score 0):

No such thing as attachments in SQL Server. You can do it 2 ways:

1. Save the file in a folder and put the path to the file in a varchar
   or nvarchar column in a table
2. Open the file in a Stream and read the stream into a byte array. Put
   that into a varbinary column in a table.

1 is good if this is being done by a web site and so the path is always relative to the same process on the same machine, or this is a single-user app on a desktop or something.

2 is more flexible: if the user has access to the database then they have access to the contents of the file.